# Using Map() with typescript in VSCode shows error message

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6, visual-studio-code, typescript-typings

When using Map() with typescript and VSCode I get the error message: `Can not find name "Map()"` with VSCode even thou compiling and executing works fine and without errors.

**How can I get rid of the error message?**

I am not sure if this is a bug within VSCode or with my configuration. I assume the later.

Here is my tsconfig.js file:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "target": "es6",
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "sourceMap": false,
        "outDir": "dist",
        "baseUrl": "."
    },
    "include": [
        "src/**/*",
    ]
}
```

VSCode: v1.19.1
typescript: v2.6.2
node.js: v8.7.0

Comment: In order to help you, we need to see the code that causes the error. Please read [mcve] for tips on creating a good code example that will attract the answer you seek. Also read [ask] for tips on asking a good question.